# I want to send data from c# to php

Tags: c#, php

I want to send a string (data) from C# to PHP but I am unable to receive data in PHP . Here is my C# code

```
    string deviceUrl ="http://localhost/CBIRS/clusteringdata.php";
    HttpWebRequest reqDevice = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(deviceUrl);
    reqDevice.Method = "POST";
    string deviceData = "status="+ data;
    byte[] postDeviceBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(deviceData);
    reqDevice.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    reqDevice.ContentLength = postDeviceBytes.Length;
    Stream requestDeviceStream = reqDevice.GetRequestStream();
    requestDeviceStream.Write(postDeviceBytes, 0, postDeviceBytes.Length);
    requestDeviceStream.Close();
```

and my PHP code is as follows.

```
   if(isset($_POST['status']))
   {
   $tempdata=explode('$',$_POST['status']);
   var_dump($tempdata);
   }
   else
   {
 echo "Data not recieved";
   }
```

after running C# application when I run PHP file it always goes to else part. How can I correct it?

Comment: Did ever someone wondered that there are lots of users with a user name like user[0-9]+ asking c# questions? Having a look at the account indicates that the account was just created today... strange strange...

Comment: oh... the guy changed the user name

Answer (score 1):

You aren't encoding the POST data. When you send POST data, the values must be URL encoded. I suspect there is a special character in `data` that is causing PHP to fail to parse the POST data.

To encode the value:

```
string deviceData = "status="+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data);
```

Comment: Sir when i am trying to use 
                          HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data)
the compiler is generating an error that 
                          HttpUtility.UrlEncode
can not be used in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `$tempdata` variable is never used in your PHP.

Have you tried to display the response of your request in your C# program ? Add another `echo "hello";` out of your condition to see if the connection works.